# Change css depending on parent class

Tags: jquery

I need help with the following problem. I need to change css property (background) to something depending on the class name of the parent. This is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="types">
  <ul>
    <li class='car'><a href='#'>Car</a></li>
    <li class='bus'><a href='#'>Bus</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to change `background-image` of the `a` tags. If I'm in `li.car`, then background will be `images/car.png`, and if in the `li.bus`, then `images/bus.png`.

I can't figure out where is the problem. This is how I started, and this works.

```
$('#types ul li a').css('background', "url('./images/skills/cooking.png') 
   center center no-repeat");
```

But when I change it to something like that, it won't work:

```
$('#types ul li a').css('background', 
   "url('./images/skills/'+($(this).parent().attr('class'))+'.png') 
   center center no-repeat");
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code inside quotes won't get executed unless you specifically invoke it `eval` or the `Function` constructor. Try bumping it outside the quotes and it should work.

```
$('#types ul li a').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background', "url('./images/skills/" + ($(this).parent().attr('class')) + ".png') center center no-repeat");
    });
```

Comment: I wrote bad quotes up there. I have exactly this code but it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Ah, you need to create a context for '$(this)'. I'm unfortunately on mobile at the minute so I cant be entirely helpful but if you use '.each' and change the CSS there it should work. '$("#types ul li a").each(function() { $(this).css(<as above>); });'

Comment: Thank you DevlshOne! StackOverflow doesn't play very nice when answering on mobile! No problem, Martin.